# How to add a PGP key to a Github bot?

Tags: github

According to this [article](https://github.blog/2019-08-15-commit-signing-support-for-bots-and-other-github-apps/), Github now supports signing commits with a bot. After reading the documentation, I think there are a few things I need to do to make it work:

1. Generate a GPG key
2. Add the GPG key to the bot account
3. Configure the bot account to use the GPG key

I am stuck at step 2 - I could not find anywhere I can add the GPG key to the bot account. I developed a Github app and I clicked through all its configuration, but did not find the place to add that. This is definitely doable according to that screen shot in the article. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Per their support, as of today Sept 29, 2023, you cannot add a gpg key to a bot. To get a bot to have signed/verified commits you will have to use their commit APIs https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git?apiVersion=2022-11-28 and it will automatically sign for you. Their docs are not clear about this so I hope this helps someone not waste time implementing it the wrong way.